# Hide BottomNavigation bar after a specific scrolling distance

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

I want to implement a custom behavior that would hide the BottomNavigation bar only after a specific scrolling distance has been reached when scrolling down but show it back immediately on scroll up.

This is what I've done so far.

```
    class BottomNavigationBehavior<V : View>(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>(context, attrs) {

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, directTargetChild: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int
    ): Boolean {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray, type: Int
    ) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type)
        child.translationY = max(0f, min(child.height.toFloat(), child.translationY + dy))
    }
}
```

Which works but it shows/hides the Bottom bar immediately when user starts scrolling on both up/down directions which is not what I'm after.